# Type class that extends an abstract class

Tags: typescript

I have several classes that extend an abstract class with a static method:

```js
abstract class Model {
   {...}
   public static findAll() { ... }
}

class ModelA extends Model { ... }
...
class ModelZ extends Model { ... }
```

Now, I want to write a function that takes a class that extends my abstract class as argument

```js
function myFunction(model: typeof Model) {
...
model.findAll();
...
}
```

But I get the following error: `Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.ts(2684)`

[image]

How can i do that ? I don't want to write `model: typeof ModelA | ... | typeof ModelZ`

I also tried :

```js
function myFunction<M extends typeof Model>(model: M)
```

[image]

I'm using sequelize if it may help.

Comment: [I can't reproduce this error.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgsgewCYFNkEBvAKAQoAcBXEZAS1gUmAkYQDN6A7XAQWTIAFAEoSAX1KTSKNBhwFkfBPgAeEfL3l5CE0jNTosO5AC0V6zbm2K9pDtW7x62bggC2ATwBij566F3EwAuBAhPSnxsDmNFMTIKIMUAOi5eAWERAG4pfS9fJzYAhUIRUny-Iu4hEqUyoA) What version of TS are you using? IIRC there was a PR relating to abstract constructors merged recently.

Comment: I'm using typescript 4.2.3

Comment: is the code here a minimal example - can you provide more context for the code if not? It is not reproducible in the playground when replicated literally, so something else must be interfering. This error should be emitted if you try to instantiate an abstract class, so you must be initializing it in the function. Can you confirm?